# YA Urban Fantasy about a teenage male who becomes a wizard, cover may have had a raven, and title was like a Shakespeare saying

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

An average teenage guy is working at some fast food place, somehow gets magic, and ends up in a cage with this werewolf girl and they get intimate. They get out and he eventually becomes pretty powerful I think. It was very modern and witty, though my description may make it seem otherwise. Urban fantasy for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing Shakespeare about it, but *[Hold Me Closer, Necromancer](http://articles.latimes.com/2010/nov/21/entertainment/la-ca-lish-mcbride-20101121)* by Lish McBride fits every other point. Teen protagonist, working in fast food, winds up caged with a female werewolf, becomes powerful, snarky. Cover has a raven.

[image: Book Cover - Hold Me Closer, Necromancer]

> Take Samhain Corvus LaCroix — skateboarder, vegetarian, college dropout. He's also a fry cook at the fast-food restaurant Plumpy's and has no idea he's a necromancer until he plays a game of potato hockey in the parking lot and inadvertently plants a tuber into the tail-light of a stranger's Mercedes-Benz.
>
> Sam isn't happy to be a fry cook. "Working here just proved that the only thing separating me from a monkey was pants," he quips in the book's opening chapter. He's even less happy to be roughed up then kidnapped by the Mercedes owner, who, unknown to him, is the most powerful necromancer in all of Seattle — a necromancer who forces Sam to train with him or be killed.
>
> There's inherent humor in a teen who's leading an ordinary American life, suddenly discovering his world isn't what it seemed. Sam's mom is a witch, it turns out. His deadbeat dad? A necromancer. The girl with whom he finds himself caged? A "friendly but possessive nymphet" who happens to also be a werehound (half werewolf, half dog).
>
> Similar to Rick Riordan's "The Lightning Thief" and "The Red Pyramid," "Hold Me Closer, Necromancer" exploits these comic juxtapositions, having Sam react the way any slacker would when confronted by what he learns: with sarcasm and sass. His interactions with co-workers, friends and enemies are chock full of humorous one-liners that are, more often than not, wittily matched by whomever he's talking to.

It was followed up by a sequel, *Necromancing the Stone*, where Samhain has to deal with an arranged marriage, dead werewolf royalty, sexy sasquatches, and gladiatorial gnomes.

Comment: But I understand the confusion about the title; I mix up Shakespeare and Elton John all the time. ;)

Comment: Incidentally, I enjoyed this book and its sequel, *Necromancing the Stone*.